# `delete eval` and `delete Function`; effects on JS injection attacks

Tags: javascript, security, code-injection, javascript-injection

I discovered today that you can `delete eval` and `delete Function` in JavaScript.

Is this an effective measure of hindering the kind of JS injection attacks relying on obfuscated code?

Are there significant downsides (i.e., breaking popular libraries that utilize these but possibly shouldn't)?

It certainly doesn't stop the effects of someone inserting a script tag on your page, but it might make it much more difficult to get that script tag inserted?

Comment: I think jQuery uses `eval()` to implement things like `$.getScript()`.

Comment: Deleting `Function` seems very dangerous to me, it will impact something like `if (x instanceof Function)`

Comment: security.stackexchange.com might be a better place for a question like this. SO is for questions about problems you're having in specific code, not opinionated discussion.

Comment: You can't delete `Function`. It can easely be obtained in another way: `alert.__proto__.constructor === Function => true`.

Comment: ... or: `var Function = (function(){}).__proto__.constructor;` and `Function` is back.